failed to load config from vite.config.js
I am creating a react app by following steps :
1. npm create vite@latest .
2. npm install

When I am running the command npm run dev Then i encounter this error : error message
Environment and Package Configuration
Environment Details:

Node version: v22.12.0
Npm version: 10.9.0

Package Configuration (package.json):
{
  "name": "context-api",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.17.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^9.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.16",
    "globals": "^15.13.0",
    "vite": "^6.0.3"
  }
}

Vite Configuration
Vite Config File (vite.config.js)
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});


I hope I will find my answer bcz I am seraching for a while but till now I am not able to solve it .

Thanks @jonrsharpe I am very thankful for you for this help actually i was solving this issue by past 2 hours .
